# Azure application insights showing duplicate log entry for Node js application

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-application-insights

We have a node js application and configured application insight using application insight key in launch.json, but in azure application insight showing duplicate log entry, I tried in google and also stackoverflow but unable to solve the issue.

My appInsights.js code is as follows,

```
const appInsightsObj = require("applicationinsights");

module.exports.initAppInsights = (appInsightKey, appName) => {
appInsightsObj.setup(appInsightKey)
    .setAutoDependencyCorrelation(true)
    .setAutoCollectRequests(true)
    .setAutoCollectPerformance(true, true)
    .setAutoCollectExceptions(true)
    .setAutoCollectDependencies(true)
    .setAutoCollectConsole(true, true)
    .setUseDiskRetryCaching(true)
    .setSendLiveMetrics(true)
    .setDistributedTracingMode(appInsightsObj.DistributedTracingModes.AI_AND_W3C);
appInsightsObj.defaultClient.context.tags[appInsightsObj.defaultClient.context.keys.cloudRole] = appName;
appInsightsObj.start();
}

module.exports.trackEvent = (name, properties) => {
   const telemetry = appInsightsObj.defaultClient
   telemetry.trackEvent({
      "name": name,
       "properties": properties
 })
}
module.exports.insightObj = appInsightsObj;
```

and log.js file is as follows,

```
 const { appConfig } = require('../../config');
 const appInsights = require('./appinsights')
 const {AzureApplicationInsightsLogger}  = require('winston-azure-application-insights');
 const log = require('winston');
 require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
 const path = require('path')
 const _ = require('lodash');
 appInsights.initAppInsights(appConfig.get("appinsights_key"), appConfig.get("app_name"));

 var transportRotatingFile = new log.transports.DailyRotateFile({
    filename: 'loyalty_service_%DATE%.log',
    dirname: appConfig.get('logfile_location'),
    datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    zippedArchive: true,
    maxSize: '20m',
    maxFiles: '14d'
 }); 
 transportRotatingFile.on('rotate', function(oldFilename, newFilename) {
 // any code while rotating log files.
});

 log.add (new AzureApplicationInsightsLogger({client: appInsights.insightObj.defaultClient}))
 log.add(new (log.transports.Console)({level: 'info', 'timestamp':true, 'json': false}))
 log.add(transportRotatingFile)
 module.exports = log;
```

In launch.json defined the appInsightKey and value and based on that it should read and connect to the application insights.

Azure application insights log entry,
[image]

Can anyone suggest me what should be the cause ? and how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Nivari What are the cloud role name for the duplicate entries? Can you post the traces entries queried from logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the cause and solution.

**Cause** - We are using both winston-azure-application-insights and applicationinsights.
Both serves the same functionality, so in azure application can see duplicate entries.

**Solution**:- when I comment winston-azure-application-insights code changes it worked fine, can not see duplicate entries in the application insights.

in log.js, commented below line,

```
//log.add (new AzureApplicationInsightsLogger({client: appInsights.insightObj.defaultClient}))
log.add(new (log.transports.Console)({level: 'info', 'timestamp':true, 'json': false}))
log.add(transportRotatingFile)
module.exports = log;
```